# Position element relative to parent element

Tags: css, css-position, fixed

For example I have fixed nav, is there a way to anchor the list items to the bottom of the nav? I attempted to give the list items a fixed position too but this messes up their layout as you can see at [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qfaxsLr/4/)

here is my code:

```css
#nav {
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #157FFB;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eeeeee;
}

#nav>ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#nav>ul>li {
  display: inline;
  /*these two lines were my attempt at anchoring the list items to the bottom f the #nav, but it throws everything out of wack*/
  position: fixed;
  top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="align_left"><a href="#">LOGO</a></li>
    <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Repairs/Upgrades</a></li>
    <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Networking</a></li>
    <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Remote Backups</a></li>
    <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Data Recovery</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `fixed` or `absolute` position it takes an element out of the flow of the document and hence they stack up on top of each other when you apply those positions to the `li` elements.

Instead you should be absolutely positioning the `ul` block to the bottom of the `#nav`:

```
#nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
#nav > ul>li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you wish to have the list elements at the bottom of your header. Just change `position: fixed;` to `position: relative;`. This keeps the elements flow along with the flow of the page.

Here is your solution:

```css
#nav{
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    background-color: #157FFB;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eeeeee;
}



#nav > ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav > ul>li{
    display:inline;
    
    /*these two lines were my attempt at anchoring the list items to the bottom f the #nav, but it throws everything out of wack*/
    position: relative; 
    top:50px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="align_left"><a href="#">LOGO</a></li>
            <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Repairs/Upgrades</a></li>
            <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Networking</a></li>
            <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Remote Backups</a></li>
            <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Data Recovery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to be anchored to the bottom of an element, but still remain in the flow of the page, try using [relative positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). That essentially means you give the `#nav` element relative positioning, and you give the `li` elements relative positioning as well:

```css
#nav {
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #157FFB;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eeeeee;
}

#nav>ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="align_left"><a href="#">LOGO</a></li>
    <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Repairs/Upgrades</a></li>
    <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Networking</a></li>
    <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Remote Backups</a></li>
    <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Data Recovery</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This seems to work pretty well, please tell me if it doesn't.

The problem you encountered was that fixed positioning put them all in a mess. Fixed positioning positions ALL the items relative to the viewport, so if you had all the `li`s with

```
position: fixed;
top: 45px;
```

They would all go in the same spot.